# How to to display a bmp image on my c little program on Windows?

Tags: c, sdl

I'm learning actually how to program with C and I have a little problem. I want to display one image on my program but I don't know why that doesn't function. The image i want to display doesn't appear. I see only a black background.

The file with the main function

```
#include stdlib.h
#include stdio.h
#include SDL/SDL.h

void pause();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL, *imageDeFond = NULL;
  SDL_Rect positionFond;

  positionFond.x = 0;
  positionFond.y = 0;

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  SDL_WM_SetIcon(SDL_LoadBMP("sdl_icone.bmp"), NULL);
  ecran = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);

  SDL_WM_SetCaption("Chargement d'images en SDL", NULL);

  /* Chargement d'une image Bitmap dans une surface */
  imageDeFond = SDL_LoadBMP("lac_en_montagne.bmp");

  SDL_BlitSurface(imageDeFond, NULL, ecran, &positionFond);

  SDL_Flip(ecran);

  pause();

  SDL_FreeSurface(imageDeFond);
  SDL_Quit();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void pause() {
  int continuer = 1;
  SDL_Event event;
  while (continuer) {
    SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type) {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        continuer = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what error messages are you receiving? what is happening in comparison to what you expect to happen?

Comment: I only have a black layout without any image, as i didn't insert any image on my code.

Comment: I don't receive any error messages, only the fact that the image doesn't display .

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: The question says Windows, but the code looks like SDL - can you add tags to more precisely identify your library/environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the full path of the bitmap images. If the images are in the same directory as the program your current code will work after enclosing the includes with <>.